# deviding an even and an uneven number

Tags: excel, office-2013, vba

I am very happy to discoverd this site. I get very good help. Hope you guys can help me with another problem. I want to round a number. Lets say I have a number 39 if I devide this into 2 then I get 18.5. Which makes very logical. But when you are counting in persons then you can't cut a person in half. So I am looking for a formule in vba. I tried the round function

```
group=39
devideby = 3 'devideby can be 2 or 3
test = round(group/devideby)
```

If I do this I get test=20. I want to have 2 or 3 separate answers: if devided by the number 2 then I want to have 20 and 19. If devided by 3 then I want to have 13, 13 and 13. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
Dim arrOutput(2)

Select Case divideby
    Case 2
        arrOutput(0) = Int(group / divideby)
        arrOutput(1) = group - arrOutput(0)
        arrOutput(2) = 0
    Case 3
        arrOutput(0) = Int(group / divideby)
        arrOutput(1) = Int((group - arrOutput(0)) / 2)
        arrOutput(2) = (group - arrOutput(0)) - arrOutput(1)
    Case Else
        MsgBox "Error"
End Select
```

It's not very elegant but I think it does what you are asking